# Rails convention confusion for altering config files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

So, I'm not having a problem so much as I am confused by two different conventions that I see used around the web for changing the Rails config files.

Specifically, I see these two statements used often:

```
config.autoload_paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/arbitrary"
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/arbitrary)
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/app/arbitrary/**/"]
```

First, is there any difference n using the `<<` operator vs the `+=` operator?
Second, is it considered a better practice to use `Rails.root` as opposed to `config.root`?

Can some of these conventions only be used in certain combinations?  I just hate not knowing something so seemingly basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**difference between `<<` and `+=`**

`config.autoload_paths` is an Array. For an Array object, `<<` push ONE object to the array, while `+` joins two array to create a new array. So if you only have one object to be appended to the existing array, `<<` is preferred for performance because no new object will be created. If you want to append another array to the existing array, you have to use `+`.

Yo know, `a1 =+ a2` is equal to `a1 = a1 + a2`.

**`Rails.root` v.s. `config.root`**

`Rails.root` is just the root of Rails app.
If `config.root` is used in a Rails app, it should be same as `Rails.root`. But it can also be used in Engines, where it will be the Engine's root. If `config.root` is used in a Rails app, you may not have to change it to use the app as an Engine.

Answer (score 0):

`<<` adds a single value while `+=` adds an array of values. The `%w(...)` notation is just a shortcut for an array of strings.

Check the source for the `Rails.root` method:
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails.rb#L83

so it uses `config.root` anyhow because

```
Rails.application.config == Rails.configuration
```

evaluates to `true`. This is also the object you get passed for the configure blocks in config/application.rb and config/environments/ files.

Comment: Your answer is basically as good, but I'm giving the check mark to the first responder.  Also, his explanation of how config.root could affect Engines was good to know.

Comment: Please don't worry :) Thanks a lot for the consideration.